# Dual boot grub screen not display using NVIDIA Grapgic card But can display by onboard VGA

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. After installing the Nividia driver for my Graphics card I restarted my PC and the grub boot screen is not displayed (I see a blank screen) and the PC boots into Ubuntu.

The grub boot is still working but just not displaying. The reason I'm saying this is because if I press the down arrow key 6 times and hit enter  it goes into windows.

If I use the onboard VGA on to boot, the grub screen shows up. How can I make my GPU show the grub screen like onboard VGA does?

Comment: Adding on to the above question. when i press Ctl + ALT+ F1, goes to command line mode,The graphic card also not displaying out and its function.

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Comment: The question is quiet old, but if the problem is still current, Could you add the question the version of the NVIDIA driver in use?